# Como ordenar o dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-3, razor, dropdownlist

Como posso ordenar o *DropdownList*?

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.id_pessoa, "Pessoa", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("id_pessoa", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.id_pessoa, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Qual é o tipo da propriedade `model.id_pessoa`?

Comment: Poderia colocar o código do seu controller?

Answer (score 1):

No controler onde você cria a lista, você precisa usar `.OrderByDescending()` ou `OrderBy()` e colocar o campo que gostaria usando a expressão.

Veja mais nesta pergunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344805/linq-orderby-descending-query

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou!